# php second foreach doesn't write out values

Tags: php

I have a problem with displaying my data. I have data in the following

```
filter_name        filter_value
Hard Drize Size    16GB
Hard Drize Size    32GB
Screen Size        7''
Screen Size        8''
```

And I want to present it like this.

```
Hard Drize Size
16GB
32GB

Screen Size
7''
8''
```

What I want in my php code is to check if the filter_name is in the $temp array and if it isn't then add it to $temp array so it won't cause duplicate entries. The problem I'm getting now is when I use the same data to do a second foreach inside the loop I get no data and my sql is correct. So I don't know how to out put the values. With the second foreach it only prints out the first $filter_name["filter_name"] and that all.

php:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
{
    $filters = "<div class=\"filters\">         
    <div class=\"apply-filters\">Filters</div>";
    $temp = array();        
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($stmt as $filter_name)
    {
        if(!in_array($filter_name["filter_name"], $temp)) 
        {
            $temp[] = $filter_name["filter_name"];
            $filters .= "<div class=\"filter-header\">".$filter_name["filter_name"]."</div>";
            //second loop here doesn't work with the same data.
            // test if filter_name["filter_name"] == second loop second_loop["filter_name"]
            // ten write out second_loop["filter_value"] e.g.
            foreach($stmt as $filter_value)
            {
                if($filter_name["filter_name"] == $filter_value["filter_name"])
                {
                    $filters .= $filter_value["filter_value"] ."<br />";
                }                  
            }

        }               
    }
    $filters .= "</div>";   
}
```

Comment: is missing `$` in `foreach($stmt as filter_value)` a typo?

Comment: 1/$aaa= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);then loop $aaa

Comment: 2/ if the data order by filter_name, you just loop once , see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do a var_dump of `$stmt` before the first and second *foreach* to look at it's form. Perhaps it's not formatted the way you think?

Why don't you loop over $stmt once and in that loop print `$stmt['filter_name']` and `$stmt['filter_value']`? Now you loop `$stmt` one "extra" time for each iteration of the first `foreach`. Instead just do a `foreach($stmt as $filter)` and `$filter`, being a associative array, should contain `filter_name` and `filter_value` for each entry.

You could then move the actual printing outside of the `foreach` and only construct your array in the loop that should look something like

```
array("Hard Drive Size" => array("16GB", "32GB"), "Screen Size" => array("7''", "8''"));
```

Then you could traverse that data structure using

```
foreach($myArray as $filter_name => $filter_values)
{
  // Print filter name header
  foreach($filter_values as $filter_value)
  {
    // print each value of the specific filter
  }
}
```

To build the presented structure you could do something like

```
...

    $filters = array();

    foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $filter)
    {
      $filters[$filter['filter_name']][] = $filter['filter_value'];     
    }

...
```

Then iterate the *$filters* structure and print it.

*Update:*

From your var_dump of `$stmt` it's clear that `$stmt` is not your result set. You should assign the result of `$stmt->fetch` to something. Like `$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and then iterate over `$result`.

Check

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: this is my var_dump of $stmt

Comment: object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(424) " SELECT pf.filter_id, f.filter_name, pf.filter_value_id, fv.filter_value, COUNT(pf.filter_id) FROM products p INNER JOIN product_filters pf on pf.product_id = p.product_id LEFT JOIN filters f on f.filter_id = pf.filter_id RIGHT JOIN filter_values fv on fv.filter_value_id = pf.filter_value_id WHERE p.department_id = 3 GROUP BY fv.filter_value ORDER BY f.filter_name, fv.filter_value" }

Comment: The problem I was having was because I using fetch instead of fetchAll() that was the problem. Thanks for you're help

Answer (score 1):

i slightly modified your code to fit your needs:

```
$temp = array();
foreach($stmt as $filter_name)
{
    if(!in_array($filter_name["filter_name"], $temp)) 
    {
        echo '<b>' . $filter_name['filter_name'] . '</b><br>';
        $temp[] = $filter_name["filter_name"];

        foreach($stmt as $filter_value)
        {
            if($filter_name["filter_name"] == $filter_value["filter_name"])
            {
                echo $filter_value['filter_value'] . '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can check a working sample here -> http://codepad.viper-7.com/aFD079

Comment: You're code works but for some reason its not working on my end!

Comment: @KDM what about that line i added on codeviper but not here, `    $temp = array();`, did you add that too? as it works for me it should for you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `$` before `filter_value`.

Change

`foreach($stmt as filter_value)`

To

`foreach($stmt as $filter_value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($stmt as $filter_name)
```

may be (i am not sure)

```
 $aaa= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($aaa as $filter_name)
```

and try

```
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$tmp_name='';
$html='';
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    if($row['filter_name'] !=  $tmp_name){
     $html .=$row['filter_name'];
    }
    $html .=$row['filter_value'];

    $tmp_name=$row['filter_name'];
}
```

echo $html;

Answer (score 0):

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) 
{
    $filters = "<div class=\"filters\">         
    <div class=\"apply-filters\">Filters</div>";
    $temp = array();        
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach($stmt as $filter)
        $temp[$filter['filter_name']][] = $filter['filter_value']; 

    foreach($temp as $filter_name => $filter_values)
    {
        $filters .= "<div class=\"filter-header\">".$filter_name."</div>";
        foreach ($filter_values as $value)
            $filters .= $filter_value."<br />";
    }

    $filters .= "</div>";   
}
```